No plugins will install on cloned site - Craft 3
I am in the process of cloning a Craft 3 site to a new server (from GoDaddy to SiteGround). I have set up the new craft space and imported the database, assets, templates, etc., which all went smoothly. But the new site won't install any plugins; any plugin install attempt gives the error below. The old site can still install plugins, and both sites are running Craft 3.9.13. How do I resolve this?
Error: The command "'/usr/local/php74/bin/php' '/home/customer/www/mydomain.com/public_html/app/storage/runtime/composer.phar' 'update' 'putyourlightson/craft-sprig' '--with-all-dependencies' '--working-dir' '/home/customer/www/mydomain.com/public_html/app' '--no-scripts' '--no-ansi' '--no-interaction'" failed.

Exit Code: 255(Unknown error)

Working directory: /home/customer/www/mydomain.com/public_html

Output:
================
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Error Output:
================

Composer output: Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8


Is the new server also using PHP 7.4? Try running php -v to confirm, and which php to confirm that the /usr/local/php74/bin/php location is still valid.

@MatsMikkelRummelhoff Yes, it is running PHP 7.4.33
